# Is there a way to not enter the same data type over and over again in a parameter in c++?

Tags: c++, parameters

Instead of doing this,

```
void myFunc(double, double, double, double, double, double, double);
```

Is there a way to limit the uses of the same data type and slim it down? I know there's probably no easier way to do this, but it would be nice if there was.

Comment: If the arguments are related, then you can bundle them into structure (POD) if you want to just pass data or in class if you want to manipulate them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is when declaring the function you could use a [variadic template function](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/5894415f-be62-4bc0-81c5-3956e82276f3/entry/c_templates_what_is_a_variadic_template_function41?lang=en). Maybe not less typing but more flexible. This returns double. For C++11 and later.

```
double myFunc() {
    return 0.0;
}

template<typename H, typename ...T> double myFunc(H head, T... tail) {
    head += myFunc(tail...);
    return head;
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    auto a = myFunc();
    std::cout << "a: " << a << std::endl;
    auto b = myFunc(1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3);
    std::cout << "b: " << b << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Outputs

> a: 0
>   b: 4.6

Comment: Yes, pardon. Updating answer.

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't. You have to list all the parameters explicitly, and there's no shorthand for repeating the same type for consecutive parameters.

If a function has lots of parameters, you might want to change it to take an object as the parameter. Or if they're all the same time, you could use an array.

Answer (score 1):

You can group them using `vector` or `list` or even `array` and pass it as an argument. However you should be sure about the order of data so that you can manipulate right data in the method.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not, this is the beauty of strong-typed programming languages.